# How to store unique set of points from two sets into new int set java (Objects)?

Tags: java, object

How to find a unique set of points from the first set that doesn't exist in the second set, without using any built-in options.

```java
public class PointSet {

    private Point[] pointArr;
}

public PointSet subtract(PointSet other) {
         // return null;
}
```

So my task is to return a new set, which has first set elements, that don't exist in the second set. An initial set should remain the same.

For example, if I have

```java
@Test
public void pointSetSupportsSubtractingAnotherSet() {
    PointSet a = getSet(new Point(1, 1), new Point(1, 2));
    PointSet b = getSet(new Point(1, 1), new Point(1, 3));

    PointSet remainder = a.subtract(b);

    assertThat(a, is(getSet(new Point(1, 1), new Point(1, 2))));

    assertThat(remainder, is(getSet(new Point(1, 2))));
}
```

Comment: Your question reads *how do I complete my task*? This is the wrong format for SO - please show your attempt in a [reprex] and describe the *specific* issues you are facing and ask a *specific* question. [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code, a quick answer using removeAll of ArrayList.

```
public class PointSet {

        private Point[] pointArr;

        public PointSet subtract(PointSet other) {
            // return null;
            PointSet pointSet = new PointSet();
            List<Point> pointArrayList = new ArrayList<Point>(Arrays.asList(pointArr));

            pointArrayList.removeAll(Arrays.asList(other));
            pointSet.pointArr = pointArrayList.toArray(new Point[pointArrayList.size()]);

            return pointSet;
        }
    }
```